# Creating custom android notification without RemoteView

Tags: java, android, remoteview

I am trying to create custom notification with custom view inside. I have to set custom array of custom objects into view. But `RemoteView` doesn't provide `getView` function. So I am asking, how to create custom android notification with custom view without `RemoveView`. Or how to get `View` from `RemoteView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to create custom android notification with custom view without RemoveView

That is not possible, sorry.

> Or how to get View from RemoteView

That is not possible, sorry.

You will need to figure out how to get your "custom array of custom objects" into something that you can implement with `RemoteViews` or via one of the extended notification styles (e.g., `InboxStyle`).