# Android Custom Notification with big animated gif image

Tags: android, image, notifications, gif, remoteview

I want to make a Custom Notification with big animated gif image. So I cannot find a solution resolve this problem. 
Because i can only use RemoteView to custome layout.
[Creating custom android notification without RemoteView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992413/creating-custom-android-notification-without-remoteview)

But RemoteView just support some basic view.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

How can i do this?

Comment: hi, have you found a solution yet?

Comment: How did you do it? I am looking to do something very similar.

Comment: Can you upload what you have done and what you need here?

Answer (score 4):

there is no good solution for this but you can use this trick :

you can set imageView to remoteView of your notification and than change the image of your imageView per gif frame and update your remoteView imageView image and your notification and you should do this on separate Thread because it is costly!

for splinting your gif to separate images you can try this sulutions :

splitting out side of your project :

https://ezgif.com/split

splitting inside your project and in runtime :

[Split GIF into frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312699/split-gif-into-frames)

please notify me if this solution worked for you